# ¿Puede "curtir" tener actualmente el significado de "machacar" que tenía en origen?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Sobre el verbo *curtir* dice el DLE:

> [**curtir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BlNrue5)
>   `Del lat. conterĕre 'machacar'.`
>
> 1. tr. Tratar y preparar la piel obtenida de un animal muerto para su uso.
> 2. tr. Dicho del sol o del aire: Endurecer o tostar a una persona o alguna zona de su cuerpo, generalmente el cutis. U. m. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. Acostumbrar a alguien a la vida dura y a sufrir adversidades que puedan sobrellevarse con el paso del tiempo. U. t. c. prnl.
> 4. tr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Castigar con azotes.

Y llego a esta palabra por un tuit que leí hace unos meses:

> Bagdad se opone al referendum, pero no puede hacer nada xq la milicia kurda ("peshmerga") se **curte** al ejército iraquí si es necesario.
>
> La única opción q tiene Bagdad para frenar el referendum es q EEUU aplique suficiente presión sobre los kurdos.
>   <sub>[Principia Marsupia (@pmarsupia), 20 septiembre 2017](https://twitter.com/pmarsupia/status/910467390613356544)</sub>

Es decir, aquí lo que está diciendo el autor es que una milicia puede derrotar fácilmente a un ejército. Para explicar el concepto utiliza el verbo *curtir*, que para mí no tiene esta connotación. Leyendo las acepciones actuales tampoco lo parece, pero me sorprende que su etimología indique [*machacar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NmS04GH), que actualmente sí tendría el sentido de "derrotar fácilmente" (*1. Golpear algo para deformarlo, aplastarlo o reducirlo a fragmentos pequeños sin llegar a triturarlo. // 2. tr. hacer polvo*).

¿Es correcto pues el uso de *curtir* como sinónimo de *derrotar*?

Comment: no creo.... curtir se hace con el objetivo de hacer algo mas resistente. cuando castigas a golpes, supongo que curtes la disciplina, el carácter y al el cuerpo por sus capacidades de sanar y volverse mas resistente. mientras que machacar es destrozarlo. si algo se curte a golpes, machacarlo es golpearlo al punto donde ya no  se puede curtir.

Comment: en una pelea... tal vez si... tal vez no... curtirse a golpes no significa ganar o derrotar, solo que la pelea estuvo acalorada. curtimos al enemigo puede significar que le produjeron una gran herida, pero no lo destruyeron. también la victoria no solo significa destruir al enemigo, sin embargo si machacaste al enemigo probablemente quiere decir que lo derrotaste.

Comment: Las pieles tradicionalmente se curten golpeandolas repetidamente.

Comment: Nótese que el verbo está usado en forma pronominal en el tuit. Lo cual me resultó algo chocante porque *curtirse (a alguien)* en Argentina es "tener relaciones sexuales (con alguien)". Algunas veces la figura de la relación sexual se usa como sinónimo de sometimiento. ¿Alguien le ha preguntado a Principia Marsupia qué quiso decir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente, en España, en lenguaje coloquial y grosero, se utiliza la expresión 'curtir a hostias' para indicar precisamente machacar, derrotar, destrozar etc. etc.

También se utilizar "curtir el lomo" con el mismo sentido, aunque es menos grosero. Si buscas esas expresiones en google verás algunos ejemplos.

Y a veces, aunque es menos común, sí que se utiliza 'te voy a curtir' o 'te van a curtir' con ese significado, especialmente para indicar la derrota en algún juego (aunque esto te lo digo como hablante del castellano que vive en España, porque no he encontrado enlaces en google con esa expresión a secas).

[Y por lo que veo en este enlace](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/curtir), en Sudamérica se utiliza 'curtir' como sinónimo de castigar.